# How do I find the end of a string in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

The code below is an i86 assembly function that will be called in c, count(char *string, char c). I'm storing the string in %esi and the character in %ecx, I'm not sure how to tell the program to stop looping when the string is over(when bytes are 0) because the cmpl function doesn't allow me to do that (operand type mismatch). I'm not sure if I'm even storing the string correctly or iterating through the string correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
.globl count
.text
#first argument is string, second is char
count:  
    push %ebp       #push old ebp to top of stack
    movl %esp, %ebp     #point ebp to same thing as esp, both pointing to old ebp

    #saving live registers
    push %esi
    push %edi
    push %ebx   

    #take values from stack
    movl $0, %eax       #set count(eax) to 0
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx     #move letter to be counted to ecx
    movl 8(%ebp), %esi  #move string to esi

lettercheck:
    cmpl %esi, %ecx #compare current letter to ecx(letter to be counted)
    incl %esi       #next letter
    je inccount     #if match inccount 
    cmpl %esi, $0       #if no match and end of string
    je end
    jmp lettercheck     #if not end of string and no match  

inccount:
    incl eax            #inc count of char
    cmpl %esi, $0       #check for end of string
    jne lettercheck     #if match and not EOS lettercheck
    jmp end         #else jmp end
end:
    pop %ebx
    pop %edi
    pop %esi
    movl %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%esi` holds a pointer, so you want to compare the byte it points at to the bottom byte of %ecx, not compare the pointer.  So your comparison instruction should be

```
cmpb (%esi), %cl
```

The `b` mean byte instead of longword, and the parens mean the value in memory pointed at by the register, rather than the register.  To check for the end of the string, you want

```
cmpb $0, (%esi)
```

for all the same reasons, plus the fact that an immediate can only be the first operand to a comparison.

Comment: When I make these changes, I still get the operand size mismatch for cmpb  (%esi), $0. Is it because esi is 32 bit?

Comment: @TinNguyen: x86 doesn't support an immediate "destination" for `cmp`, only `cmpb $0, (%esi)` where you use the immediate as a source.  This answer got the operand order mixed up for AT&T syntax.

Comment: Yes, just copied the OPs code, which had the comparison with const in the wrong order.